# python-docx Replace a URL with custom content

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

I want to write a tool that is able to process a docx file and replace urls that match a specific pattern, with different content (e.g. headings, tables, and text).

Finding the matching URL is simple enough

```
from docx import Document
from docx.opc.constants import RELATIONSHIP_TYPE as RT

doc = Document('input.docx')
rels = doc.part.rels
for r in iter_hyperlink_rels(rels):
    print(r)
```

But I'm not sure how to remove that element and place my own content at that specific location. How can I do this?

In essence, I'm trying to implement a sort of macro processor that replaces specific tags within a document with content generated using these tags.